# Specifying a name for a foreign key in Laravel migration when using the constrained() method

Tags: laravel

Laravel 8, database migrations. I know I can use the long-form :

```
$table->foreign('really_long_table_name_id', 'foreign_key_name')->references('id')->on('really_long_table_name')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

to create a foreign key with a specific name where (as in my case) the name that Laravel would automatically generate via the constrained() method :

```
$table->foreignId('really_long_table_name_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

would be too long and cause MySQL to complain.

Is it possible to use the constrained() method and specify the foreign_key_name, rather than let it be dynamically generated? As I'm struggling to see it in the documentation, or any SO searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` method to update the name of the index.

```php
$table->foreignId('really_long_table_name')
    ->constrained()
    ->cascadeOnUpdate()
    ->cascadeOnDelete()
    ->index('index_name');
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you. Silly of me, really, but I like to not have to mix methods unless necessary!